# How to embed ICC profile in DNG so darktable will use it?

Tags: darktable, dng, icc-profile

I am experimenting with linear raw DNG and ICC profiles with Darktable.

The DNG files are the result of scans using VueScan. I can add the scanner's ICC profile to the DNG. But when I open it in DarkTable, I am not sure if it is there.

If I do the same with a "raw" TIFF from VueScan then it works as expected: an embedded ICC profile is listed under *input color profile* as *embedded ICC profile*. If I don't embed (or remove) a profile then the option is missing. This is the behaviour I expect.

However, if I do the same with a DNG then I never see the *embedded ICC profile*.

There is an *embedded matrix* listed but that is due to the DNG `ColorMatrix1` tag. I've tried removing this tag (with `exiftool`) to see if that allowed the profile to be used but that didn't either.

I embed profiles like this:

```
$ exiv2 -iC- image.dng < scanner.icc
```

or

```
$ exiftool -icc_profile\<= scanner.icc image.dng
```

or

```
 $ exiftool -asshoticcprofile<= scanner.icc image.dng
```

The `asshoticcprofile` tag is defined in the spec as *a way to specify a default color rendering from camera color space coordinates (linear reference values) into the ICC profile connection space.* But DarkTable ignores it.

Can I embed a profile in a DNG and then use it in Darktable?

Comment: On dark table's website they state: "If your input image is a low dynamic range file like JPEG, or a raw in DNG format, it might already contain an embedded ICC profile which darktable will use as a default. You can always overrule darktable and select a different profile. Select “embedded icc profile” to restore the default. " https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/en/color_group.html  This implies that if there is a profile then it will work.

Comment: It's the absence of the *"embedded icc profile"* option that provoked the question. I have a DNG and I have added a profile to it but the option does not appear in darktable. If I do the same thing with a linear tiff then the option does appear. Hence the question...

Comment: I have never worked with DarkTable before, but the makers of the ColorPerfect plugin for Photoshop differentiate VueScan's "Raw DNG Format" option and the "Raw" TIFF settings, warning against the former. Perhaps that will lead you to an answer? See the "Putting out Raw Tiffs" section of  [Perfect Slide and Negative Scans](https://www.colorperfect.com/scanning-slides-and-negatives/scans/Hamrick-Software/VueScan/).

Comment: You may want to ask on pixls.us, there are many DT devs there.